# How show loaded shell files in OS X?

Tags: macos, strace

Like the following command works on Linux, have a way to show loaded files in shell?

```
echo exit | strace bash -li |& less | grep '^open'
```

The output is:

```
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)     = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On macOS, you can use this slightly different set of commands:

```
sudo bash -c "echo exit | dtruss bash -li 2>&1 | less | grep '^open'"
```

Or, if you have bash version 4 or 5:

```
sudo bash -c "echo exit | dtruss bash -li |& less | grep '^open'"
```

(As stated [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334389/87917) in the comments section)

Note:

`|&` is a shorthand for `2>&1 |` and is not available on bash 3.x that ships with macOS (it requires bash >= 4). Its purpose is to redirect both standard output and standard error to the input of the next command after the pipe.

Comment: You are tested this in what version of OS X? Not works here.

Comment: @BrunoWego I updated my bash to version 5, that's why. I updated the answer for older bash versions.

Answer (score 0):

On `macOS` `dtruss` can be leveraged much in the same way as `strace` on linux:

```
$ sudo dtruss -t open -n bash
```

There are some differences in output, although it's likely going to be most similar to your question.

```
 PID/THRD         SYSCALL(args)                                      = return
 9658/0x130527a:  open("/dev/tty\0", 0x6, 0xFFFFFFFF8ED3D6B8)        = 3 0
 9658/0x130527a:  open("script.sh\0", 0x0, 0x0)                      = 3 0
 ...
```

Additional `SYSCALL` arguments for "open" include `open_nocancel` and `open_extended`.

> **dtruss -h** will give you a complete set of options.

↳ [Dtrace Tools : Brendan Gregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html)

Comment: Technically `open`, `open_nocancel` and `open_extended` are distinct syscalls. Reference: https://sigsegv.pl/osx-bsd-syscalls/